# Making bootstrap columns vertical oriented instead of horizontal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have the following bootstrap marked up html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
    <div class="col col-md-6">
      <div class="col col-xs-12">
        <div>a</div>
        <div>b</div>
        <div>c</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col col-xs-12">
        <div>d</div>
        <div>e</div>
        <div>f</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-md-6">
      <div class="col col-xs-12">
        <div>g</div>
        <div>h</div>
        <div>i</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col col-xs-12">
        <div>j</div>
        <div>k</div>
        <div>l</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://www.bootply.com/blyGjCAkjr

I want my data to be listed vertically as per the example, so that the 2nd element is beneath the 1st, and the 3rd beneath the 2nd etc.

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
i
j
k
l
```

When the browser size is wider I want the data listed in two columns but still laid out in vertical order

```
a   g
b   h
c   i
d   j
e   k
f   l
```

I have this working so far, but I am not sure it is the best way to achieve it. Also, I want to extend this further so it can switch to 3 columns

```
a   e   i
b   f   j
c   g   k
d   h   l
```

and 4 columns as the browser is sized even wider, whilst also keeping the elements vertically orientated.

```
a   d   g   j
b   e   h   k
c   f   i   l
```

Obviously it's possible to switch between 1 and 2 columns in this way because I have done it. Is it also possible to switch up to 3 and 4 columns using only bootstrap?

Comment: you should have a look at [`Responsive Breakpoints`](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints)

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you use flexbox instead of bootstrap. Its a very powerfull css grid system. You can show 3,4,5,6 colums in one row. also you can handle easily on responsiveness. [Here is a link to an article.](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: @OP wants to use only `Bootstrap` :/

Comment: I don't care what I use as long as it is css